# Show review count outside of review template

Tags: magento-1.9, phtml, review, variables

I have a *review.phtml* template that shows the ***review count of the current product*** using this code:

```
if($this->getReviews()):
  $rc = $this->getReviewCount();
if($this->getReviewCount() == 1):
  echo '<img src="' . $this->getLogoSrc() . '" /> <strong>(' . $rc . ' review)</strong>';
elseif($this->getReviewCount() > 1):
  echo '<img src="' . $this->getLogoSrc() . '" /> <strong>(' . $rc . ' reviews)</strong>';
endif;
endif;
```

I want to show the review count somewhere else on the page(same product) by putting the code in `summary.phtml` where the default "leave a review" link is.

This doesnt work as I am sure I need to change $this to where the review.phtml template is?

Answer (score 3):

Try this code in your .phtml file

```
$product = Mage::registry('current_product');
$rc = $product->getRatingSummary()->getReviewsCount();
```

Hope this helps.